# Android - WebView to Native to Webview

Tags: android, webview, native

I have a bit of a conundrum (for myself anyways). I have a requirement to go from a WebActivity to Native then back to the same WebActivity and pass it a url. Ideally we don't want any special action in the WebActivity to accomplish this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). This allows an activity to launch another, and receives a callback when that activity finishes. You can add the url to a bundle that can be attached to the returned intent.